# Qt 5.9.2: No valid kits found on windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qmake

I've installed Qt5.9.2 for 64bit Windows 7 Operating system from this [link](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.9.2.exe), evrything was Ok till the point where I wanted to create a new GUI application project, it says that "No valid kits found", I was able to add and manage compilers for C & C++, but I am not able to find the "qmake" file to manage the Qt version. Any solution?

Comment: check in your Qt installation dir like C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\bin here you can find qmake. Just add that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's no "mvsc" folder anywhere in the Qt base folder.

Comment: just go into C:\Qt and search for qmake in file explorer u will get path. I wrote my qmake path just for reference.

Comment: Yes, I did it before, but it's kinda wierd that no qmake file was found. it says on the download section on the official website: "Qt offline installer is a stand-alone binary package including Qt libraries and Qt Creator. "

Comment: during installation u selected MinGW or VS as compiler ? please provide more details about directories inside C:/Qt

Comment: Thanks, I guess you are right. Now, I've unistall and reinstalling it with selecting MinGW and msvc 2017 64bit, because I didn't do it at the first installation, hop it will work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: MINGW]

Have a look here i am using MinGW compiler with lib. if you have VisualStudio you can select respective libraries too.

Comment: I did as mentionned aboved on your answer, now, it says that warning where "qmake" is not appropriate with my Qt version, I've checked the Qcreator version and I found that it's based on 32bit system, should I use msvc2015 32bit?

Comment: first check your compiler install same Qt libs like i have Visual studio 2017 x64 installed on my pc so i installed msvc2017-64 bit Qt libs. if you dont have any compiler you can install mingw